# Load DLLs without adding reference

Tags: .net, winforms

I am developing a windows application with the .NET Framework 2.0. Only required functionality will be visible to the user.

The complexity I am facing is, some functionality requires some external DLLs. so I want that if that functionality is not needed to user, the DLLs should not be deployed in the users machine.

One solution I thought would be to use reflection to use functions from the DLLs without adding reference and create 2 separate deployment projects - one with DLL and other without it.

Can anyone suggest other solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seems as you need a plugin system, for that use MEF

http://mef.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

@Antonio is right, you are effectively describing a plugin system.

You can use one of the `Load()` methods on the [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbe1wdx9.aspx) class as long as you can live with assemblies living in memory until your entire application has shutdown. If you need the more complicated scenario of being able to unload the assembly during runtime [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511405/loading-dll-into-separate-appdomain?lq=1) might be of use to you.